# Hide a single element in a layer - Kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

This code uses Kineticjs. I am using mouseover and mouseout events for one of the images. The layer has 2 images. I want to hide just one of them. Do I need to create a separate layer for each image?

```
img.onload = function(){
                    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                        image: img,
                        name:'iconImage',
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        //draggable: true,
                        //visible:true,
                        listening:true
                    });
                    var image2 = new Kinetic.Image({
                        x:100,
                        y:100,
                        image: img,
                        name:'iconImage',
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        //draggable: true,
                        //visible:true,
                        listening:true
                    });
                iconLayer.add(image).add(image2);
                stage.add(iconLayer);
                //stage.draw();


                image.on('mouseover',function(){
                    image.hide();

                    iconLayer.clear();
                    //iconLayer.draw();

                });

                image.on('mouseout',function(){
                    //iconLayer.clear();
                    //image.show();
                    //iconLayer.draw();

                    image.show();
                    iconLayer.draw();

                    //stage.draw();
                });

                }
```

which is the best way to use hide() and show() functions?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a separate layer.

Just use myShape.hide() and myShape.show()

Answer (score 1):

As markE said, you can use `hide()` and `show()` but don't forget to redraw your layer after hiding/showing your shape with`stage.draw()`.

Answer (score 1):

@tussh I agree with your observation on hiding = mouseout as the event handler will no longer handle events for the hidden objects.
What can work for is this,
Add a transparent rectangle on top of the image or alternately a transparent image (alpha) and set the event handler on it instead. The object will always be there, invisible to eye but still detecting all your events.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the above answers to make sense of my answer.

In my code I am adding 'mouseover' event on image1 and hiding image1
Then I add 'mouseout' on image1 and show image1. When I do hide-draw and show-draw the image flickers and does not completely disappear. **I am guessing Kinetic takes hiding=mouseout as the image is no longer there**.

However 'mouseover' event on image1 then hide image2 works just fine with the hide-draw and show-draw method. This scenario works for me. Thank you for the help folks